# Date in calendar sets back to current date when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, calendar

I have one calendar on UI and initially when the page is loaded the current date should be shown in the calendar. I am achieving this by:

```
$('#single_cal1').attr("placeholder", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

Now If user selects another date in calendar I am able to update the date in the calendar box as per the selection.

Issue: When the page is refreshed the date in the calendar box gets back to the current date. And its evident because on page refresh my code

```
 $('#single_cal1').attr("placeholder", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```

runs and sets the date to current.

Kindly note that I have "user selected date" available in localStorage all the time.

Current Code:

```
<script>
 $('#single_cal1').attr("placeholder", new Date().toLocaleDateString());
</script>
```

Code I want to achieve:

```
<script>
var x  = localStorage.getItem('date'); // OUPTUT OF DATE IS 2016-08-19T14:22:53.339Z
var y  = x.toLocaleDateString();
     $('#single_cal1').attr("placeholder",y);
    </script>
```

But I get error. And I kind of know why I am getting error. Is there any way I can format the date I got from local storage. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
var y  = new Date(x).toLocaleDateString();
// new Date('2016-08-19T14:22:53.339Z').toLocaleDateString()
// returns 8/19/2016
```

Comment: Thank You so much. So basically local storage does not understand that I have saved "Date Object to it" So explicitly I need to pass x to "Date". Am I right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3prcf54c/1/
@Unbreakable X is a string *'2016-08-19T14:22:53.339Z'* and thus, _String_ doesn't have the *.toLocaleDateString()* method as it's not a _Date Object_

Comment: You're welcome ! JS Updated to match the input placeholder style

Comment: Yup. @GrégoireFruleux is right. If you do `console.log(typeof (x))` you will see its is a string not a date object. In order to that we use `new Date(x)`. So, now if you do `console.log(typeof (new Date(x)))` you will see it is converted to a `object` and we can call `.toLocaleDateString()` upon it now safely.